# Textarea not generating from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a website using `jquery-1.11.1` where I want a `<textarea>` to be spawned whenever I click on the link which only shows on `mouseenter` on a div. But I'm getting an error in my console,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: inputdivEditor is not defined (Please ignore JSFiddle errors)

[image: Error in my page]

I've absolutely no idea why I'm getting this. Here are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=divEditor-]").each(function () {
        var content = $(this).html();
        var targetID = $(this).attr('id');
        var txtID = 'input' + targetID;

        $('<textarea id="input' + targetID + '" name="' + txtID + '" >' + content + '</textarea>').insertBefore(this).css('display', 'none');
        var button = "<a onclick='activateDivEditor(this, " + txtID + ")' class='custom-edit-button editDiv' id='active" + targetID + "'>Embed Code</a>";

        $(this).on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).prepend($(button));
            $(this).css('position', 'relative');
        });
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function () {
            $('.editDiv').remove();
        });
    });
});

function activateDivEditor(btn, txtId) {
    var targetID = $(btn).parent().get(0).id;
    var update = "<a onclick='deactivateDivEditor(this, " + txtId + ")' class='custom-edit-button updatediv' id='deactive" + targetID + "'>Update</a>";
    var cancel = "<a onclick='cancelactivateDivEditor(this)' class='custom-edit-button cancel' id='cancelactive" + targetID + "'>Cancel</a>";
    var targetClass = $('#' + targetID).attr('class');
    var targetWidth = $('#' + targetID).width();
    $('#' + targetID).css('display', 'none');
    $('#input' + targetID).css('display', 'block').css('width', targetWidth - 2).css('height', '125px');
    $('#input' + targetID).parent().css('position', 'relative');
    $(update).prependTo($('#input' + targetID).parent());
    $(cancel).prependTo($('#input' + targetID).parent());
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hb9ow8oq/)

How can I generate a textarea whenever I click on the button link? Need this help badly. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the line `var update = "<a onclick='deactivateDivEditor(this, " + txtId + ")' class='custom-edit-button updatediv' id='deactive" + targetID + "'>Update</a>";`, for example, `txtId` is not wrapped in quotes and is therefore not a string. It should be `deactivateDivEditor(this, \'" + txtId + "\')` in your case.

Comment: Your code could use a bit of a restructure to avoid adding all those inline `onclick="..."` handlers. You're using jQuery anyway, so why not take advantage of its simple event delegation system with `.on()` to setup those handlers? Then you wouldn't need to worry about getting all the single versus double quotes in all the right spots in building up those strings.

Comment: Your functions aren’t defined because in JSFiddle you have selected the option “onLoad” on the left side. This puts it into another event listener function which blocks your elements from accessing your functions. Use “No wrap - in `<head>`” instead.

Comment: Also IDs need to be unique, also anchor onclick handlers need a preventDefault if you are not suing them for navigation away from the page